# Slide Effect happening too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I call this functions on onmouseover and onmouseout for several divs.

```
//Takes effect on divs with id, 62,63,64,65...
function slide_it(id){

    $('#options_'+id).slideToggle('slow');

}
```

The problem is that if I move my mouse over and then mouse out, then again, mouse over and then mouse out. If I do this several times, the slide effect happens the same number of times I moved my mouse over and out of the div, as expected.

But I can't figure out how I can do this **once**? I can set a variable, but I have several divs that this function is used by and I can't think of a simple way of doing this rather than storing things into an array, but this is messy!

I really appreciate any help on this that is simple to implement!

Thanks all for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you call [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), use [`.stop(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), this ends the current animation (if there is one), and since you're chaining, will immediately start the animation you're providing, like this:

```
$('#options_'+id).stop(true).slideToggle('slow');
```

[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

> When `.stop()` is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped. If, for instance, an element is being hidden with `.slideUp()` when `.stop()` is called, the element will now still be displayed, but will be a fraction of its previous height. Callback functions are not called.

Example: if you hover in and out fast, i doesn't wait to finish sliding it, it stops it and begins sliding out as soon as the mouse leaves.

Comment: Thanks Nick, stop() is very useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

try to remove your onmouseover and onmouseout handlers from div which was slided. YOu can do it inside `slide_it(id)` function

Answer (score 0):

Bind the events with `jQuery`s `one()` method: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: This executes an event handler one time only, this doesn't really have anything to do with animation at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is because all effects are added to a effects-queue and played one after the other.

Clearing this queue is simple, just add clearQueue():

```
function slide_it(id){

    $('#options_'+id).clearQueue().slideToggle('slow');

}
```